# HSQLDB - Override the default name for the unique index created with a primary key

Tags: hsqldb, rdbms

I can create a primary key specifying its name with some thing like this:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

The engine also creates a unique index named something like `SYS_IDX_11905`.
I don't know of a way to specify its name at creation and if I try to rename it with

```
ALTER INDEX SYS_IDX_11905 RENAME TO MY_TABLE_ID_UINDEX
```

I get `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SYS_IDX_11905`.

Is there any way in which I can specify the name of the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user cannot drop or rename the automatically created indexes. See also http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_sql_conformance for the `sql.sys_index_names` property, which can be set to use the same name for the index as the primary key constraint.